# Break node connections from within Property Editor?

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, shaders, properties

To create a node and connect it to a Property, I can click on the color-coded dot next to the Property name. This launches a pop-up menu of permitted input nodes for that data type.

So how do I BREAK a connection from the Property Editor? I know I can go into the Node Editor and break the connection there. But I should be able to just break the connection directly in the Property Editor, restoring that Property to its default status and UI.

In Maya, I can do this by right-clicking the attribute name and choosing "Break Connection". But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this in Blender. The documentation wasn't helpful, I searched and searched and couldn't find anywhere this magic colored dot was even mentioned. I wasted a great deal of time trying to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Click the *linked* shader property and select *Disconnect* from the list in order to *break the connection*. You can also select *Remove* if you'd like to get rid of the *linked node:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found that, but it's not consistently in all pop-up menus. It's missing sometimes.

Comment: ARGH!!! The pop-up menu is limited to the size of the window!!! Items are being cut off!! Serves me right for having the Property Editor in another window so I can maximize viewports. ARGHHHHH

Comment: Even if, that's exactly what you wanted. If the menu is cut off, file a bug report. I can not confirm for linux and osx @AaronF.Ross

Comment: I will file a bug report. I hope they don't tell me I need to test it on the beta version, I'm already in too many beta program. Thanks

Comment: Good news is that they are going to reply, quickly. Last time I filed a bug report for Maya I didn't get any answer @AaronF.Ross I would recommend do yourself a favour and take Blender or Maya as (buggy) as they are and don't try to compare each other, you are wasting your time IMHO.